# jqplot - uncaught exception - No data

Tags: jqplot

my json file looks like

```
{"items":[
{"date":"2012-03-12","scoreMin":"9","scoreMax":"25","scoreAverage":"20.39","scoreSTD":"3.86","scoreCount":"133","count20":"73","count25":"46"},
{"date":"2012-03-13","scoreMin":"9","scoreMax":"25","scoreAverage":"20.9","scoreSTD":"4.25","scoreCount":"99","count20":"56","count25":"46"},
{"date":"2012-03-14","scoreMin":"9","scoreMax":"25","scoreAverage":"20.9","scoreSTD":"4.25","scoreCount":"99","count20":"56","count25":"46"},
{"date":"2012-03-15","scoreMin":"9","scoreMax":"25","scoreAverage":"20.9","scoreSTD":"4.25","scoreCount":"99","count20":"56","count25":"46"},
{"date":"2012-09-15","scoreMin":"5","scoreMax":"24","scoreAverage":"18.55","scoreSTD":"5.65","scoreCount":"100","count20":"45","count25":"0"},
{"date":"2012-09-16","scoreMin":"5","scoreMax":"24","scoreAverage":"18.55","scoreSTD":"5.65","scoreCount":"100","count20":"45","count25":"0"},
{"date":"2012-09-17","scoreMin":"5","scoreMax":"24","scoreAverage":"18.59","scoreSTD":"5.67","scoreCount":"99","count20":"45","count25":"0"},
{"date":"2012-09-18","scoreMin":"5","scoreMax":"24","scoreAverage":"18.64","scoreSTD":"5.67","scoreCount":"100","count20":"46","count25":"0"}
]}
```

and my script is

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Date Axes</title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jqplot/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jqplot/jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="jqplot/plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="jqplot/jquery.jqplot.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h2>
        Some Statistics</h2>
    <div id="chartCanvas" style="height: 400px; width: 1000px; align">
    </div>
    <br />
    <script type="text/javascript">

    $(function(){
    $(document).ready(function(){
    alert('Document ready');
    var objArrayData=[];
    var objArray = [];    
    $.getJSON("data.json",function(data){

        $.each(data.items, function(i,data){
        objArrayData[i] =("['" + data.date + "'," + data.scoreAverage + "]");
        }); 

        alert( 'Fetched ' + objArrayData.length + ' items!'); 
        console.log('object Data ' + objArrayData); 
        objArray = ("[" + objArrayData + "]");
        console.log('object Array' + objArray);  

        var plot = $.jqplot('chartCanvas', [objArray], {
                    title:'Rubric Average Scores',
                    gridPadding:{right:35},
                    axes:{xaxis:{renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                    tickOptions:{formatString:'%#m/%y'},
                    //tickOptions:{formatString:'%b-%y'},
                    min:'March 30, 2012',
                    tickInterval:'1 month',
                    angle: -30,
                    }},
                    yaxis:{label:'Average Score',
                    },
                    series:[{lineWidth:3, markerOptions:{style:'square'}}]
                   });

  });      

    }); 
    return false;
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

I am getting uncaught exception- No data error
Before plotting the chart, I am printing the array and there are all the values that I need.

What is missing? Where am I doing wrong?
Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you are feeding data to the objArrayData array in the way you are doing here. The data doesn't become an array just because there are square brackets surrounding them (it will only appear pretty and satisfying and confusing in the `cosole.log`).

Use `array.push()` instead of the way you are doing it here.

And also make sure you make the `data.scoreAverage` a number before parsing it to the array.
You can do it using `parseFloat()` function.

So finally you can feed the data to the array like this.

```
objArrayData.push([data.date,parseFloat(data.scoreAverage)]);
```

Here's the modified working code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Date Axes</title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../jquery.jqplot.min.js"></script>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="../plugins/jqplot.dateAxisRenderer.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../jquery.jqplot.css" />
</head>
<body>
    <h2>
        Some Statistics</h2>
    <div id="chartCanvas" style="height: 400px; width: 1000px; align">
    </div>
    <br />
    <script type="text/javascript">

        $(function(){
            $(document).ready(function(){
                var objArrayData=[];
                var objArray = [];    
                $.getJSON("data.json",function(data){

                    $.each(data.items, function(i,data){
                        objArrayData.push([data.date,parseFloat(data.scoreAverage)]);
                    }); 

                    console.log('object Data ' + objArrayData); 

                    var plot = $.jqplot('chartCanvas', [objArrayData], {
                                title:'Rubric Average Scores',
                                gridPadding:{right:35},
                                axes:{xaxis:{renderer:$.jqplot.DateAxisRenderer,
                                tickOptions:{formatString:'%Y-%m-%d'},
                                //tickOptions:{formatString:'%b-%y'},
                                min:'March 30, 2012',
                                tickInterval:'1 month',
                                angle: -30,
                                }},
                                yaxis:{label:'Average Score',
                                },
                                series:[{lineWidth:3, markerOptions:{style:'square'}}]
                               });

              });      

            }); 
            return false;
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Hope this helps.

PS: Make sure you learn about arrays a little more.